# express js API promise synchronization problem

Tags: node.js, express, es6-promise

I am trying to create a async GET api in expressJS using promises. however for some reason, results aren't getting synced properly. Api takes a url, parses its parameters (each parameter is website link) from url, sends a request to each link, gets the inner text of `<title>` tag, appends it to a string and returns it as a response. Here's the code

```js
var parseLinks = (addresses) => {

let html = `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>result</title>
    </head>
    <body>
`;

let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
        html = html + "<ul>";
        addresses.forEach(address => {
            request.get(`https://${address}`, (req, res, body) => {
                const $ = cheerio.load(body);
                const title = $('title').text(); 
                html = html + `<li>${address} - "${title}"</li>`;
            });            
        });

        html = html + `
            </ul>
            </body>
            </html>
            `
        resolve(html)
    } catch (error) {
        html = html + `
            <h1>an exception has occurred during parsing</h1>
        </body>
        </html>
        `
        reject(html)
    }
});

return promise; 
};

app.get("/I/want/title", (req, res) => {

let addresses = url.parse(`${host}${req.url}`, true);

new Promise(resolve => resolve([].concat(addresses.query.address)))
    .then(addresses => parseLinks(addresses))
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        res.writeHead(200, header);
        res.write(data);
        res.end();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });

 }).listen(port, () => 
    console.log(`server listening on http://localhost:${port}`)
 );
```

expected result should be for url **http://localhost:3000/I/want/title/?address=www.google.com&address=www.dawn.com/magazines**

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<h1> Following are the titles of given websites: </h1>

<ul>
   <li> google.com - "Google" </li>
   <li> www.dawn.com/events/ - "Events - DAWN.COM" </li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

but my result is

```html
<html>
<head></head>
<body>

<h1> Following are the titles of given websites: </h1>

<ul>

</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to `resolve` *inside* the `get` request callback, not outside.

Comment: can you explain a bit further?

Comment: With your code as it is right now, the `resolve` will be called right after the request is done. You need to call `resolve` inside the callback you give to the `request.get`

Comment: can you show any example? whole concept is really getting frustrated for me.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea with the `Promise` goes in the right direction. The problem is that your requests alter the `html` variable only after you already have `resolve()`d your Promise.

They instead each should create a promise and you need to wait for all of these promises (the requests) resolve.

**What you need to do:**

- return a Promise for each result of `request.get()`
- use `map()` instead of `forEach()` which will return an array of these Promises
- wait for all of these Promises to resolve with `Promise.all()` to create a new Promise, which resolves when all of the given Promises are resolved
- join all the result lines

This would look like that:

```
Promise.all(addresses.map(address => {
  return new Promise(resolve => request.get(`https://${address}`, (req, res, body) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(body);
    const title = $('title').text(); 
    resolve(`<li>${address} - "${title}"</li>`);
  });            
}).then(results => {
  html += results.join()
})
```

Remember that the `html` variable is filled reliably only inside of the `then()` callback, even if it is defined globally.